# Error: Expected one matching request for criteria ... found none

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, jasmine

I have seen lots of questions about this error but having spent the best part of today trying each solution out I need your help.

I am trying to test this service which is an http get request

```
getTrainInformation(url: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(url,
            {
                params:
                {
                    expand: 'true'
                }
            }
        ).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

Here is my test:

```
import { HttpTestingController, HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TrainInformationService } from "./traininformation.service";

describe('traininformation service', () => {
    let service: TrainInformationService;
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [TrainInformationService]
        });        

        service = TestBed.get(TrainInformationService);
        httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });
        
    it('should perform a GET', () => {
        
        const url = service.getFullUrl('BOP');

        const urlParam = { param: 'expand', value: 'true'};
        
        const urlWithParams = `${url}?${urlParam.param}=${urlParam.value}`;
        
        service.getTrainInformation(urlWithParams).subscribe();                 
        
        const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(urlWithParams);
        console.log('req is ' + req); 
        
        req.flush('Some');
        
        // httpTestingController.verify();            

    });
    
});
```

When the test runs, it fails with:

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL:
> <<the_expected_url>>, found none.

If I change the test so that I comment out the calls to expectOne and flush and call verify, so the test becomes:

```
it('should perform a GET', () => {
        
        const url = service.getFullUrl('BOP');

        const urlParam = { param: 'expand', value: 'true'};
        
        const urlWithParams = `${url}?${urlParam.param}=${urlParam.value}`;
        
        service.getTrainInformation(urlWithParams).subscribe();                 
        
        // const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(urlWithParams);
        // console.log('req is ' + req); 
        
        // req.flush('Some');
        
        httpTestingController.verify();            

    });
```

The error I now see is:

> Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: GET <<the_expected_url>>

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. I have faced the same issue as you where I couldn't get a handle on the request and this happens most likely because the request has params and we can't match it by the params although the URL seems to be one to one. If there are no params, I can get a handle easily on the request.

To get a handle on the request with params, I use a different signature of `httpTestingController.expectOne` where I pass in an object with the matching criteria.

```
    afterEach(() => {
      httpTestingController.verify();
    });

    it('should perform a GET', () => {
        
        const url = service.getFullUrl('BOP');

        const urlParam = { param: 'expand', value: 'true'};
        
        const urlWithParams = `${url}?${urlParam.param}=${urlParam.value}`;
        
        service.getTrainInformation(urlWithParams).subscribe(response => {
          expect(response).toBe('Some'); // put an assertion here (optional).
        });                 
        
        const req = httpTestingController.expectOne({
           method: 'GET',  // find open Http request that is a get request.
        });
        console.log('req is ' + req); // should have a handle on it now
        // below asserts the params
        expect(req.request.params.toString()).toBe('${urlParam.param}=${urlParam.value}');
        req.flush('Some');
                    
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wouldn't have been able to solve it without your help.